# multiuser in symfony using fosuserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have three tables in my database: Simpleuser and Admin and StudentUser, I would like use this 3 table to connect in my symphony app , but I know that with fosuserBundle I should configurate just one table to be able to connect to the application.
I already change the first one using config.yml 
here :

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: MyApp\UserBundle\Entity\StudentUser
```

i'm searching  solution that let me log in my symfony application with many users , any one have an idea ?
thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PUGXMultiuserBundle](https://github.com/PUGX/PUGXMultiUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) to handle multiple user classes.